# Metal API Validation Enabled Location Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using the location display feature.

When I install the application on the phone with Xcode works fine.

But when I use the application without installing the application with Xcode, it throws from the application does not show the location.

What is the problem? I get the output when running with Xcode:

> Metal API Validation Enabled

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

public extension CLLocation {
  func bearingToLocationRadian(_ destinationLocation: CLLocation) -> CGFloat {

    let latitud1 = self.coordinate.latitude.degreesToRadians
    let lon1 = self.coordinate.longitude.degreesToRadians

    let latitud2 = destinationLocation.coordinate.latitude.degreesToRadians
    let lon2 = destinationLocation.coordinate.longitude.degreesToRadians

    let dLon = lon2 - lon1

    let y = sin(dLon) * cos(latitud2)
    let x = cos(latitud1) * sin(latitud2) - sin(latitud1) * cos(latitud2) * cos(dLon)
    let radiansBearing = atan2(y, x)

    return CGFloat(radiansBearing)
  }

  func bearingToLocationDegrees(destinationLocation: CLLocation) -> CGFloat {
    return bearingToLocationRadian(destinationLocation).radiansToDegrees
  }
}

extension CGFloat {
  var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
  var radiansToDegrees: CGFloat { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

private extension Double {
  var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(CGFloat(self).degreesToRadians) }
  var radiansToDegrees: Double { return Double(CGFloat(self).radiansToDegrees) }
}
```